# Django, Markdown and SageCell

Tags: python, django, django-models, markdown, sage

I am building a blog with Django. This blog is made up by posts whose content would benefit a lot from using Markdown syntax. But some of this posts also include [SageMath cells](http://sagecell.sagemath.org), which process some Python-Sage Code enclosed in some special `div`s, as in [this tutorial](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/static/about.html?v=076b8b4093fa6a45a81e291c7e2b8fb7). Now every Markdown engine parses the Python code, and both tools (Markdown and SageMath) come into conflict.

Which would be smartest approach for implementing these posts?

Comment: This is just an idea. But output 2 different cells. One filled with markdown and another filled with sagemath. In the markdown file have comments that are placeholders for sagemath results. parse the sagemath and insert them back into the placeholders.

Comment: @AlanSTACK but what if the two contents are heavily intertwined? See for instance http://buzzard.ups.edu/ to get an idea of a example

Comment: I've tried to get a discussion on this going at [sage-cell Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sage-cell/uSPHUmmS3Fs).

Comment: @kcrisman thank you very much!! this is great